# Execution failed for task 'app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, ui-testing

I'm trying to build UI tests for my Android application in Android Studio. The problem is that I can't run them. I get the message: Execution failed for task 'app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies' which I couldn't find what it's about. When I run my application, it starts perfectly, but when i try to run tests it shows the mentioned message. My build.gradle is lsited below:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ba.etf.pkks.eldaralmin.libraryapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()

maven {
    url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
// Supports Android 4.0.3 and later (API level 15)
compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:2.0.0@aar'

// Supports Android 2.1 and later (API level 7), but not optimal for later Android versions.
// If you only plan on supporting Android 4.0.3 and up, you don't need to include this.
compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-legacy:2.0.0@aar'

// Convenience library to launch the scanning and encoding Activities.
// It automatically picks the best scanning library from the above two, depending on the
// Android version and what is available.
compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-integration:2.0.0@aar'

// Version 3.0.x of zxing core contains some code that is not compatible on Android 2.2 and earlier.
// This mostly affects encoding, but you should test if you plan to support these versions.
// Older versions e.g. 2.2 may also work if you need support for older Android versions.
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:2.1'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'

}
```

My run/debug configurations for tests are in the image below:

http://pokit.org/get/?5b2509c64e5049b1b168c99b95313d5e.jpg

Can anyone help me to figure out where the problem is?

Answer (score 7):

In your apps `build.gradle` add the following within `android { }`:

```
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
}
```

But why would lead to such?

> When instrumentation tests are run, both the main APK and test APK share the same classpath. Gradle build will fail if the main APK and the test APK use the same library (e.g. Guava) but in different versions. If gradle didn't catch that, your app could behave differently during tests and during normal run (including crashing in one of the cases).
>
> To make the build succeed, just make sure both APKs use the same version. If the error is about an indirect dependency (a library you didn't mention in your build.gradle), just add a dependency for the newer version to the configuration ("compile" or "androidTestCompile") that needs it. You can also use Gradle's resolution strategy mechanism. You can inspect the dependency tree by running ./gradlew :app:dependencies and ./gradlew :app:androidDependencies.

Comment: Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I had this problem more than a year ago, and solved it, but didn't update the post with an answer.

Comment: Sadly this does no work for me. Am using compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" and all my other versions are higher however

Comment: Just fixed it using this related solution instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37717407/2734863

Comment: Thank you so much, after hours of effort this fixed it! I also recommend making sure compileSDKVersion matches minSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion.