# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'. > Dependency Error. See console for details

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-espresso

[image]Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.

> Dependency Error. See console for details.

After adding the the following dependencies in app.gradle file -

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
// add this for intent mocking support
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
// add this for webview testing support
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'
```

Console Logs -

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (25.0.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.

> Dependency Error. See console for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 28.459 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:1 warning
>   Information:See complete output in console

Answer (score 11):

I got the same probleme,when I add the following code in my app's `build.gradle` within `android { }`,that's ok.

`configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
}`
you can get reason in this page
[Execution failed for task 'app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558737/execution-failed-for-task-apppreparedebugandroidtestdependencies)

Answer (score 9):

You need to add this line to your dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
```

to force using the latest version of library

You can also try to exclude conflict packages like I did for `espresso-contrib` library

```
dependencies {
    ext.JUNIT_VERSION = '4.12'
    ext.AA_VERSION = '4.0.0'
    ext.SUPPORT_VERSION = '24.1.1'
    ext.ESPRESSO_VERSION = '2.2.2'

...

    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    /**
     * AccessibilityChecks
     * CountingIdlingResource
     * DrawerActions
     * DrawerMatchers
     * PickerActions (Time and Date picker)
     * RecyclerViewActions
     */
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESPRESSO_VERSION") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happen because of library version conflict in the debug app and test app. Add this under android{} tag

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1'
    }
}
```